# onClick() button Radio button value not change us JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, radio-button

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" value="red" id="radio"/>
<input type="button" value="js" onclick="myChange()"/>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    function myChange() {
        document.getElementById("radio").value="green";
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the button the value of the radio button `red` is not changing to green, help me to find the solution.

Thanks to the replies in advance.

Comment: Look at the developer console!

Comment: You are NOT calling `myChange()` **anywhere**

Comment: PS: Why not use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your HTML is missing the closing `"` for one of the attributes. You need `type="button"`
- JavaScript is case sensitive. You want `Id` not `ID`.
- There is a `By` in the method name.
- You haven't defined a `green` variable. Perhaps you mean the string `"green"`?
- `onclick="myChange()"` will call the function `myChange` when the button is clicked, you haven't defined that function.

Such:

```
function myChange() { 
    document.getElementById("1").value="green"; 
}
```

Note that there will be no visible change in a radio button when you change its value.

Comment: Click the radio button and submit the form. Then look at the submitted value on the server.

Answer (score 1):

IDs cannot start with a number, so change your id:

```
<input type="radio" value="red" id="radio"/>
```

You must also change your js:

```
function myChange() {
  document.getElementById("radio").value="green";
}
```

Then, lastly fix the HTML syntax error here:

```
<input type="button" value="js" onclick="myChange()"/>
```

Comment: @Selva please note the function part in this answer as this is a crucial part you left out.

Answer (score 0):

It is getElementById, you forgot By.

```
document.getElementById("id").value = "green";
```